# pods not starting in replication controller

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

hello I was trying to run `Sample file`
from this page: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/replication-controller/operations/

and I  have replication controller but no pods:

```
$ kubectl describe  rc frontend-controller
Name:       frontend-controller
Namespace:  default
Image(s):   redis
Selector:   app=frontend
Labels:     state=serving
Replicas:   0 current / 2 desired
Pods Status:    0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
No volumes.
No events.
```

when I try `kubectl get events` there is no information about it.
I can create standalone pod but any replication controller doesn't work

Where can I find some useful log to debug it (`systemctl status kubelet` on master node doesn't say  anything about it)
Maybe I can set Kubernetes to more verbose ?

Edit:

### component statuses

```
$ kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS      MESSAGE                                                                                       ERROR
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz: dial tcp       127.0.0.1:10252: getsockopt: connection refused   
scheduler            Healthy     ok                                                                                             
etcd-2               Healthy     {"health": "true"}                                                                             
etcd-3               Healthy     {"health": "true"}                                                                             
etcd-1               Healthy     {"health": "true"}                                                                             
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health": "true"}
```

Comment: What does running `kubectl describe` on the replication controller say?

Comment: Is your Controller Manager started and healthy? `kubectl get cs`

Comment: I added more info, sims like controller-manager is unhealthy

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it.
It turns out that I put a file `kube-controller-manager.yaml` to wrong location(after recreation of cluster with file placed in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` it's ok ), thanks for help.